# "Better still, camels": meaning?

Tags: expressions

I'm trying to understand the "better still" of this expression (from [this](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-10925456) BBC article):

> "Imagine you're on the maiden flight of that new ultra-modern
>   aircraft, the Dreamliner. And you notice it's being towed to the
>   runway by donkeys. `Better still, camels`"

Does it means that camels would be better for that than donkeys, or the opposite?

Answer (score 2):

As [I think] stangdon and Flater mean, the "better still" does not mean that camels would be better than donkeys for towing an airplane. The author means that you would do better to imagine camels, instead of imagining donkeys.

In your brief abstract the author seems to mean that it would be very strange to see a modern airplane being towed by animals; it is incongruous, because the airplane seems to be part of a modern technological society while the draft animal seems part of a rural low-tech society. And perhaps for reasons of his own he thinks of camels as even more old-fashioned than donkeys, or more proper to a very low-tech society.